# SIGN EXTEND FROM 6 TO 16-BITS

Tags: verilog

I want to take IR1 and seperae it to different variables, then i want to take it again and assign the first 6-bit of it to the first 6-bit of c1 ,after that sign extend the sixth bit of c1 to 16 which i already declared c1 to a 16-bits.

```
module IR(IR1,ra,rb,rc,c3,c2,c1,clk,opcode);
  input [15:0]IR1;
  input clk;
  output reg ra,rb,rc,c3;
  output reg [15:0]c1,c2;
  output reg [3:0]opcode;

  always@( posedge clk ) begin
   opcode <=IR1[15:12];
   ra<=IR1[11:9];
   rb<=IR1[8:6];
   rc<=IR1[5:3];
   c3<=IR1[2:0];
   c1<=IR1;
   c2<=IR1;
end

always @( posedge clk ) begin 
  while(c2[5]==1||c2[5]==0) begin 
   c2[5:0]<=IR1[5:0];
   c2[6]<=c1[5];
   c2[7]<=c1[5];
   c2[8]<=c1[5];
   c2[9]<=c1[5];
   c2[10]<=c1[5];
   c2[11]<=c1[5];
   c2[12]<=c1[5];
   c2[13]<=c1[5];
   c2[14]<=c1[5];
   c2[15]<=c1[5]; 
  end 
 end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

**Concatenation** `{ valueA, valueB}` combined with **Replication** `{REPEAT{ value }}` can mimise the code required for a manual sign extension.

```
localparam WIDTH = 16;

output reg [15:0]c1;
output     [15:0]c2;

assign c2 =  { {WIDTH-6{c1[5]}} , c1[5:0] };
```